# What are the consequences of 'welfare cliffs', but in quantity discounts?

Tags: price-discrimination

Welfare cliff is a situation when your marginal net tax rate is negative, so earning more money leaves you with less disposable income because you lose some of your transfers. Something like that can happen if a producer offers a discount for bulk purchase that's greater than additional money you need to spend to meet the bulk threshold.

For example, if you're ordering food, the food delivery app may offer to waive fixed delivery fee of 5 dollars if your order is larger than 30 dollars. That creates kind of a 'welfare cliff' where ordering a 29 dollar meal is more expensive than ordering a 31 dollar meal. On the one hand, such pricing model promotes incentives to buy orders larger than the threshold, but on the other hands, it feels kinda 'wrong' - the same marketing dollars could be spread out to offer a smooth version of the same discount without a cliff, but it's unclear to me it would actually work better. Is there any research on that cliff pheomenon? When is it profitable to do a cliff discount, and when is it profitable to do smooth discounts?

One clear benefit is that 'cliff' discounts are simple to administer and explain to customers, but that seems like a solvable problem for simple alternative functions/digital businesses.

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. Imagine I offer you 3 items for the price of 2.  You might buy 1 or you might buy 3 but you will probably not buy 2.  It might persuade you to spend twice as much as you would have spent without the offer even if the value you put on the third item is relatively low, and if the marginal cost to me is small enough, this may increase my profit over offering a discount on the second item large enough to tempt you to buy it.